# Changing font in jEditable control only when placeholder text is displayed

Tags: jquery, css, jeditable

I have a div that I'm turning into a jEditable control with code like this:

```
         $(".ed-fld").editable("/url",
            {
              placeholder: "(Edit)", 
              tooltip: "Click to edit", 
              indicator: "Saving. . ."
            } 
         );
```

It works fine.

Now, I would like to add an effect such that when the control is displaying the placeholder text it displays in a grey color.  When the control contains actual text, it should obey the regular styling.

Is this possible through jEditable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `placeholder` string is directly assigned to the element's innerHTML, so you can include HTML tags in it with a class, e.g.

```
$('.ed-fld').editable('/url', {
    ...
    placeholder: '<span class="placeholder">(Edit)</span>'
});
```

Then you can style the `placeholder` class, e.g.

```
.placeholder { color: gray }
```

See it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/william/6VUHh/40/.

Comment: I just tried, and that didn't happen. Could you try to reproduce that in jsfiddle?

Comment: @Nikita Silverstruk , in response to your question about it showing all the HTML in the box, what fixed it for me was using single instead of double quotes to surround the placeholder text. For example:  

    placeholder:"<span style="font-size:12px">Edit...</span>"

will show as <span style="font-size:12px">Edit...</span> when the users clicks the box, however,  

    placeholder:'<span style="font-size:12px">Edit...</span>'  

will show up just fine.